# Gson to parse a recursive json structure

Tags: json, recursion, gson

I am using gson to build Java objects from json strings. The json structure builds a "query" that can contain either

a) rules, combined by a condition (AND or OR)

b) one ore multiple queries again, combined by a condition (AND or OR)

(a) is simple, but how can a implement (b)?

here comes a sample of the json:

```
{
  "condition": "AND",
  "rules": [
    {
      "id": "amount",
      "field": "amount",
      "type": "double",
      "input": "text",
      "operator": "greater",
      "value": "80"
    },
    {
      "condition": "OR",
      "rules": [
        {
          "id": "text",
          "field": "text",
          "type": "string",
          "input": "text",
          "operator": "contains",
          "value": "rewe"
        },
        {
          "id": "text",
          "field": "text",
          "type": "string",
          "input": "text",
          "operator": "contains",
          "value": "aldi"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and this my java class, representing the json:

```
public class QueryBuilder {
    public String condition;
    private List<Rule> rules;
    private List<QueryBuilder> children;  // <-- should I do it like this?

    public static QueryBuilder buildFromJson(String json) {
//      Gson g = new Gson();
        Gson g = new GsonBuilder()
                //.registerTypeAdapter(Rule.class, new JsonCustomSerializer ())
                .create(); 

        return g.fromJson(json, QueryBuilder.class);
    }

    public String toJson() {
        Gson g = new Gson();
        return g.toJson(this);
    }

    public String getCondition() {
        return condition;
    }

    public void setCondition(String condition) {
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    public List<Rule> getRules() {
        return rules;
    }

    public void setRules(List<Rule> rules) {
        this.rules = rules;
    }



    public List<QueryBuilder> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<QueryBuilder> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With that JSON kind of payload you won't be able to get Gson to map it directly to some class hierarchy. Your commented line is in the right way: you need a custom converter. Use the new `TypeAdapter`. There, you would need to detect wether you are reading a condition/rule or a query. The good news is that the set of field names is different so you just need to read the first field and then branch to read a full `Rule`, `Query` or whatever you detected.

Take a look at the class [`JsonReader`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html), specially the `peek` method.

Also, remember that you can delegate your parsing to other `TypeAdapter`. That's the *recursion* part that you ask for. From a [`Gson`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/Gson.html) object you can ask for a `TypeAdapter` for any object. See method `getAdapter`. You can use it with your `Rule` class for example.

There is no single solution. You can write all the parsing and do all the recursion, you can use delegation, etc.